# Availability of Office.CoercionType.Image

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm developing an add-in for Office with Angular using the Office Common API for Javascript, and I have to allow users to insert images at the current selection.

I'm using the following code:

```
private insertImage(asset: Asset, quality?: IAssetQuality): void {
    this.getDownloadUrl(asset, quality).subscribe(url => {
      const correctedUrl = this.getCorrectBase64Url(url);
      Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(correctedUrl, 
          {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image}, result => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            console.error('failed to insert image', result);
        }
    });
  }, err => console.log('Unable to retrieve downloadUrl:', err));
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine in all Office online application as well as in Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus, but it doesn't work in my local version of Office, which is Microsoft Office Standard 2016 for Windows. When reading through the documentation, it seems like ImageCoercion should be supported in Office 2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a mistake in the documentation?

Comment: Tobias, when you say "standard" can you provide more details on what you have? what build and what SKU?  MY guess is that you are in MSI and the API was not backported to that SKU.

Comment: I'm running a 32-bit version of Office, and the version number is 16.0.4266.1001. I have tried to retrieve the SKU, but unfortunately with no luck. Could you maybe provide a quick hint for getting the SKU?